MediaWiki API Error: badrequest while attempting to change password using changeauthenticationdata
Description:
I am trying to use the MediaWiki API to change a user's password with the changeauthenticationdata module. However, every time I make the request, the API returns an error with code badrequest and the message "Failed to create change request.". Here are the details of the information and code I’m using:
Auth Manager Info:
{
    "id": "MediaWiki\\Auth\\PasswordAuthenticationRequest",
    "metadata": {},
    "required": "primary-required",
    "provider": "Password-based authentication",
    "account": "exampleUser",
    "fields": {
        "password": {
            "type": "password",
            "label": "New password:",
            "help": "Password for authentication.",
            "sensitive": ""
        },
        "retype": {
            "type": "password",
            "label": "Retype new password:",
            "help": "Password again to confirm.",
            "sensitive": ""
        }
    }
}

Request Code:
const changeAuthenticationData = async () => {
  const API_URL = "https://examplemediawikiapi.org/w/api.php";

  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Cookie":
      "wiki_newToken=6b77e36991035df08e8821254f2f22cc; wiki_newUserID=43082; wiki_newUserName=exampleUser; wiki_new_session=uj4m5upe2gt8k9kmcsup52prrgqd4k0j",
  };

  const body = new URLSearchParams({
    action: "changeauthenticationdata",
    changeauthtoken: "a26ed1d857c652d47f911c9e3bc8522a675259cf+\\",
    format: "json",
    changeauthrequest: "MediaWiki\\Auth\\PasswordAuthenticationRequest",
    password: "examplepass",
    retype: "examplepass",    
  });

  try {
    const response = await fetch(API_URL, {
      method: "POST",
      headers,
      body,
    });

    const result = await response.json();
    console.log("Response:", result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
};

changeAuthenticationData();

Response Returned:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "badrequest",
        "info": "Failed to create change request.",
        "*": "See https:/....."
    }
}

What I’ve Tried:

Retrieved the changeauthtoken from the query&meta=tokens module with
type csrf.
Ensured the authmanagerinfo provides
MediaWiki\Auth\PasswordAuthenticationRequest as the
authentication request type.
Verified that the password and retype
fields match.

Questions:

What could be causing this error?
Am I using the changeauthrequest or changeauthtoken parameters incorrectly?
Is there any additional step I should take to make this request succeed?

Thanks for your help!
